# Is there a web frontend for cifs/smb like Synology Filestation?

Tags: website, server-message-block, cifs, interface

I´m looking for a Web-Frontend to browse, download and upload files exported from another Server via SMB.
It has to offer ldap/AD-login for Users and honor the permissions from the Share.

I know most NAS-OS offer this functionality, but it is restricted to Shares provided by the NAS itself.

Is my googlefu weak or isn´t there any (recent) FOSS Projekt?

Cheers
Jochen

Comment: **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines.

Comment: I agree with hb, but you may take a look for truenas or truenas alternativ on google for a nicer search